# How to cancel Async Send Socket in C# application

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, asyncsocket

I have an application which simply pulls items from a queue and then attempts to send them asynchronously via a network socket.

I am experiencing some issues when things go wrong or the client aborts the host socket.

Here is some of my code: I think it may explain better than my words:

Here is my `SocketState.cs` class which holds the socket and related info:

```
public class SocketState
{
    public const int BufferSize = 256;
    public Socket WorkSocket { get; set; }
    public byte[] Buffer { get; set; }   

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor receiving a socket
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="socket"></param>
    public SocketState(Socket socket)
    {
        WorkSocket = socket;
        Buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    }
}
```

Here is my `SocketHandler.cs` class which controls most of the socket operations:

```
public class SocketHandler : IObserver
{
    # region Class Variables
    private static readonly log4net.ILog Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
    private SocketState _state;
    private OutgoingConnectionManager _parentConnectionManager;
    private int _recieverId;
    private readonly ManualResetEvent _sendDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public volatile bool NameIsSet = false;
    private ManualResetEvent _receiveDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    public String Name;
    public readonly Guid HandlerId;
    # endregion Class Variables

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public SocketHandler(SocketState state)
    {
        HandlerId = Guid.NewGuid();
        _state = state;       
        _state.WorkSocket.BeginReceive(_state.Buffer, 0, SocketState.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), this._state);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set the receiver id for this socket.
    /// </summary>
    public void SetReceiverId(int receiverId)
    {
        _recieverId = receiverId;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops / closes a connection
    /// </summary>
    public void Stop()
    {
        CloseConnection();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used to set this connections parent connection handler
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="conMan"></param>
    public void SetConnectionManager(OutgoingConnectionManager conMan)
    {
        _parentConnectionManager = conMan;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns if the socket is connected or not
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool IsConnected()
    {
        return _state.WorkSocket.Connected;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Public Class that implements the observer interface , this function provides a portal to receive new messages which it must send
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"> Event to execute</param>        
    public void OnMessageRecieveEvent(ObserverEvent e)
    {
        SendSignalAsync(e.Message.payload);           
    }
    # region main working space

    # region CallBack Functions
    /// <summary>
    /// CallBack Function that is called when a connection Receives Some Data
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ar"></param>
    private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            String content = String.Empty;
            if (ar != null)
            {
                SocketState state = (SocketState)ar.AsyncState;
                if (state != null)
                {
                    Socket handler = state.WorkSocket;
                    if (handler != null)
                    {
                        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

                        if (bytesRead > 0)
                        {
                            StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder();
                            Sb.Append(Encoding.Default.GetString(state.Buffer, 0, bytesRead));

                            if (Sb.Length > 1)
                            {
                                content = Sb.ToString();

                                foreach (var s in content.Split('Ÿ'))
                                {
                                    if (string.Compare(s, 0, "ID", 0, 2) == 0)
                                    {
                                        Name = s.Substring(2);
                                        NameIsSet = true;
                                    }

                                    if (string.Compare(s, 0, "TG", 0, 2) == 0)
                                    {
                                        LinkReplyToTag(s.Substring(2), this.Name);
                                    }
                                }
                                _state.WorkSocket.BeginReceive(_state.Buffer, 0, SocketState.BufferSize, 0,
                                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), _state);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            CloseConnection();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Call Back Function called when data is send though this connection
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="asyncResult"></param>
    private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        try
        {
            if (asyncResult != null)
            {
                Socket handler = (Socket)asyncResult.AsyncState;
                if (handler != null)
                {
                    int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(asyncResult);
                    // Signal that all bytes have been sent.
                    _sendDone.Set();
                    if (bytesSent > 0)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {                
            Log.Error("Transmit Failed On Send CallBack");
        }
        //Close socket as something went wrong
        CloseConnection();
    }
    # endregion CallBack Functions

    /// <summary>
    /// Sends a signal out of the current connection
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="signal"></param>
    private void SendSignalAsync(Byte[] signal)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_state != null)
            {
                if (_state.WorkSocket != null)
                {
                    if (_state.WorkSocket.Connected)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            _sendDone.Reset();
                            _state.WorkSocket.BeginSend(signal, 0, signal.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback),
                                _state.WorkSocket);
                            _sendDone.WaitOne(200);
                            return;
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Log.Error("Transmission Failier for IP: " + ((IPEndPoint)_state.WorkSocket.RemoteEndPoint).Address, e);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //Close Connection as something went wrong
            CloseConnection();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error("An Exception has occurred in the SendSignalAsync function", e);
        }
    }     


    /// <summary>
    /// Call this to Close the connection
    /// </summary>
    private void CloseConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            var ip = "NA";
            try
            {
                if (_state != null)
                {
                    ip = ((IPEndPoint)_state.WorkSocket.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                //Cannot get the ip address
            }
            OutgoingListeningServer.UpdateRecieversHistory(_recieverId, ip, "Disconnected");

            try
            {
                if (_state != null)
                {
                    if (_state.WorkSocket != null)
                    {
                        _state.WorkSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                        _state.WorkSocket.Close();
                        //_state.WorkSocket.Dispose();
                        _state.WorkSocket = null;
                        _state = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _state = null;
                Log.Error("Error while trying to close socket for IP: " + ip, e);
            }
            if (_parentConnectionManager != null)
            {
                // Remove this connection from the connection list
                _parentConnectionManager.ConnectionRemove(this);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error("A major error occurred in the close connection function, outer try catch was hit", e);
        }
    }  
    # endregion main working space
}
```

And here is my thread which will then call the `OnMessageRecieveEvent()` function in the `SocketHandler.cs` class.

```
  private void Main()
    {
        Log.Info("Receiver" + ReceiverDb.Id + " Thread Starting");
        // Exponential back off 
        var eb = new ExponentialBackoff();
        try
        {
            while (_run)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (ReceiverOutgoingConnectionManager.HasConnectedClient())
                    {
                        //Fetch Latest Item
                        ILogItem logItem;
                        if (_receiverQueue.TryDequeue(out logItem))
                        {
                            //Handle the logItem 
                           **calls the OnMessageRecieveEvent() for all my connections.                       
                                    ReceiverOutgoingConnectionManager.SendItemToAllConnections(logItem);  
                            //Reset the exponential back off counter
                            eb.reset();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Exponential back off thread sleep
                            eb.sleep();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Exponential back off thread sleep
                        eb.sleep();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.Error("Error occurred in " + ReceiverDb.Id + "receiver mains thread ", e);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error(" ** An error has occurred in a receiver holder main thread ** =====================================================================>", e);
        }
        Log.Info("Receiver" + ReceiverDb.Id + " Thread Exiting ** ===============================================================================>");
    }
```

I apologize for so much code. But I fear that it might not be something obvious so I posted all related code.

Now to further explain my issue. 
If an error happens on the socket. I get allot of `Transmit Failed On Send CallBack`. which to me means that i'm not closing the socket correctly, and there are still outstanding callback being executed.

Is there no way I can cancel all outstanding callback when i close the socket?

I am also sure there will be a few suggestions / issues with my code I posted. I would more than appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Man, this callback is just outstanding! #just_had_to

Comment: What would canceling unperformed actions mean? Are you trying to notify the callers that their actions were canceled due to socket closing? As I see it, if you have a queue of actions, and then you stop going through that queue, the queued actions are unperformed, overlooked, ignored, and canceled.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume this is for learning purposes, since writing your own networking code for other purposes is somewhat... *hard*.

Getting an exception in the send callback is *fine*. That's what exceptions are for. However, you need to *identify* the exception, rather than just catching the blanket `Exception` and pretty much ignoring all the information inside.

Handle the exceptions you can handle in the places where it's proper for them to be handled.

I'm not going to be very specific, because there's a lot of issues with your code. But one of the key things is ignoring proper socket handling - when you receive `0` bytes, it means you're supposed to close the socket. That's the signal from the other side saying "we're done". By ignoring this, you're working with a (perhaps partially) closed connection.

Please, use some networking library that can give you the guarantees (and simplicity) you need. WCF, Lindgren, whatever. TCP doesn't guarantee you'll get the message in one part, for example, so your message parsing code is unreliable. You need to use some message framing, you need to add proper error handling... `Socket` isn't a high-level construct, it doesn't work "automagically", you need to implement all this stuff on your own.

Even ignoring the network code itself, it's obvious you're just ignoring most of the complexities of asynchronous code. What's up with the `SendDone`? Either you want to use asynchronous code, and then get rid of the synchronicity, or you want synchronous code, and then why are you using asynchronous sockets?

Comment: Thanks for you comments and opinions. I think you have pointed out a good few things to me as what I actually want to achieve. At the end of the day I want reliably. Which is probably not what i have here. I followed allot of online tutorials with the async sockets.  Just to mention, the setup which its used for is more of a broadcast environment.  My client application doesn't specifically send back and ack. only tcp ack.

Comment: @zapnologica The C# samples on the internet are usually an awful mess. There's some very good C++ samples, but that means a lot of trouble, of course - and you still have to filter out the broken ones. Writing low-level networking code is really hard, you really want to have someone who does that for a living handle that, and just use their library :) I've started making some samples and tutorials about networking, but it's not going to be ready anytime soon, not to mention that it needs a lot of peer review and real-life testing. Networking is *hard*. It's a distributed system, after all.

Comment: Look, as much as I would love to dive in and learn the ins and outs of networking. This is ultimately for a live production server. And from your advice and a tad of logic from my side, It shouts Library.  It will require a fair amount of code change on my behalf, but will be worth it. Is there any specific library you could suggest?  In this case I don't have control over the clients. Do you know of this lib: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/563627/A-full-library-for-a-Socket-Client-Server-system

Comment: @zapnologica Don't be affraid of using a well tested technology for what you're doing. For example, it looks like you could easily use HTTP for the communication - HTTP is very easy to use in .NET. And it actually gives you a response - TCP `Send` will not tell you the remote server received your data.

Comment: @zapnologica You have no control over the client? That's tricky. If the communication protocol doesn't have message framing, you can't just add it on the server. What do you know about the communication? Are there ways to find the end of any given message? In any case, it probably sounds you will not be able to use any ready library for that scenario. Ouch.

Comment: Yes, that is my concern. I do have knowledge of the client. and if one had to it could be rebuild. However another department is in control of the client. It just uses a simple text based protocol. This server is basically a post box. The client connects to server, and provides its name. The server authenticates it and then literally just streams messages to the client.  There is some hope. The protocol they user has a start Delim and and end Delim.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70689/discussion-between-zapnologica-and-luaan).